# Create statement query in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a below create statement query in my Oracle Database

```
CREATE TABLE FQ01_AA_FUTURE_INSTALLMENTS_M1 ( RECORD_ID VARCHAR (35), 
mv_seq INT (4),
sv_seq INT (4),
PAY_TYPE VARCHAR (30),
PAY_PROP VARCHAR (30),
PAY_PROP_AMT FLOAT (30),
PAY_METHOD VARCHAR (30),
PAY_AMT FLOAT (30),
JB_DATE_IMPORT TIMESTAMP)
```

Getting with the exception 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Kindly Update if anything is wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out your datatype, Try `number` instead of `int`:

```
CREATE TABLE FQ01_AA_FUTURE_INSTALLMENTS_M1 ( RECORD_ID VARCHAR (35), 
    mv_seq NUMBER (4),
    sv_seq NUMBER(4),
    PAY_TYPE VARCHAR (30),
    PAY_PROP VARCHAR (30),
    PAY_PROP_AMT FLOAT (30),
    PAY_METHOD VARCHAR (30),
    PAY_AMT FLOAT (30),
    JB_DATE_IMPORT TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: Thanks Bhushan, It is working fine. What's the difference between INT and Number usage. Is there any difference of these two ?

Comment: In Oracle INTEGER is a particular data type stored in metadata as a number with data_length 22, precision null and scale 0. Pratically INTEGER is an.... integer number!

Comment: @arunsmartarrow have a look at [oracle datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm). There is no datatype `INT` in oracle.